# Not able to cat dbfs file in databricks community edition cluster. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, dbutils, databricks-community-edition

Trying to read delta log file in **databricks community edition** cluster. (databricks-7.2 version)

```
df=spark.range(100).toDF("id")
df.show()
df.repartition(1).write.mode("append").format("delta").save("/user/delta_test")
```

---

```
with open('/user/delta_test/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json','r')  as f:
  for l in f:
    print(l)
```

**`Getting file not found error:`**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/user/delta_test/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1759925981994211> in <module>
----> 1 with open('/user/delta_test/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json','r')  as f:
      2   for l in f:
      3     print(l)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/user/delta_test/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json'
```

I have tried with adding `/dbfs/`,`dbfs:/` nothing got worked out,Still getting same error.

```
with open('/dbfs/user/delta_test/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json','r')  as f:
  for l in f:
    print(l)
```

But using **`dbutils.fs.head`** i was able to read the file.

```
dbutils.fs.head("/user/delta_test/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json")

'{"commitInfo":{"timestamp":1598224183331,"userId":"284520831744638","userName":"","operation":"WRITE","operationParameters":{"mode":"Append","partitionBy":"[]"},"notebook":{"","isolationLevel":"WriteSerializable","isBlindAppend":true,"operationMetrics":{"numFiles":"1","numOutputBytes":"1171","numOutputRows":"100"}}}\n{"protocol":{"minReaderVersi...etc
```

How can we read/cat a **`dbfs file`** in databricks with `python open method`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, this data is on the DBFS, and your code need to understand how to access it.  Python doesn't know about it - that's why it's failing.

But there is a workaround - DBFS is mounted to the nodes at `/dbfs`, so you just need to append it to your file name: instead of `/user/delta_test/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json`, use `/dbfs/user/delta_test/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json`

update: on community edition, in DBR 7+, this mount is disabled.  The workaround would be to use `dbutils.fs.cp` command to copy file from DBFS to local directory, like, `/tmp`, or `/var/tmp`, and then read from it:

```py
dbutils.fs.cp("/file_on_dbfs", "file:///tmp/local_file")
```

please note that if you don't specify URI schema, then the file by default is referring DBFS, and to refer the local file you need to use `file://` prefix (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#access-files-on-the-local-filesystem)).

Comment: Thanks @AlexOtt, I have tried using `/dbfs` and used python open file api.. `with open('/dbfs/user/delta_test/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json','r')  as f:
  for l in f:
    print(l)` still getting same error.. do I need to **manually** create `mount` point to access the file before using in python way?

Comment: It looks like that it depends on the DBR version on the community - it works just fine with DBR 6.6, but `/dbfs/` is empty on DBR 7.2

Comment: Hi Alex, could you elaborate how to workaround this issue through `dbutils.fs.cp`? I have tried the following:

`dbutils.fs.cp("databricks-datasets/README.md", "/tmp/README.md")`  --> worked

`%fs ls /tmp/README.md`  --> returns path to `"dbfs:/tmp/README.md"`

`f = open("/tmp/README.md", "r")`  --> `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/README.md'`

Comment: I've added the code example to the answer.  By default if you don't specify schema, then all references are going to the DBFS file. To use local files, use `file://`

Comment: @AlexOtt, Hi Alex, this answer is super helpful. But I have one question. This `file:///` directory is not on DBFS, so where is this dir located? I searched my local machine, but no such dir is being created. I appreciate your help!

Comment: it will be located on the driver node

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same issue and we discovered that if you're using the Azure Databricks edition instead of the Community Edition, you simply need to set the cluster to 'no isolation shared' mode. That's all you need to do to fetch from DBFS :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).