# Data Bricks Community Edition Cannot Read Uploaded Table (Was Working Before)

Tags: python, pandas, databricks, databricks-community-edition

So when I was trying to work with some ideas on DataBricks Community Edition today, I suddenly find out the python pandas can no longer read a existing uploaded table. The directories were working before, but none of my previously uploaded tables can be read any more, all return in "`File ... Not Exist`". Anyone know what we can do?

Command used:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/iris.csv')
```

File is definitely there, this also affects all my other previously uploaded files.

[image: DBFS]

[image]

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to cat dbfs file in databricks community edition cluster. FileNotFoundError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552922/not-able-to-cat-dbfs-file-in-databricks-community-edition-cluster-filenotfounde)

Answer (score 1):

How did you load the csv? from blob? if from blob you probably have not mounted.

Can you try read as spark? If you can't read then the file is corrupt. If you can, try apply `sdf.to.pandas()`.

```
sdf = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/tables/iris.csv', header="true", inferSchema="true")
```

Comment: it's a community edition, there are limitations there. see the answer that I linked...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, so it works with spark. I am using DBR 7.6, so I will need to find a way to deal with this.

Comment: One more question, how do I mount the "/FileStore/" so that I can access it like before? Thanks

Comment: Try this documentation and let us know if you run into issues https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html#language-python