# Cannot find '/dbfs/databricks-datasets' in my notebook

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition, databricks-ml

I am using the Databricks community edition and working through the [ML intro](https://databricks.com/discover/introduction-to-data-analysis-workshop-series/ml-scikit-learn) tutorial.

I am able to `%fs ls databricks-datasets/COVID/covid-19-data/us-states.csv`, but not able to read it through pandas

```py
>>> df = pd.read_csv("/dbfs/databricks-datasets/COVID/covid-19-data/us-states.csv")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File /dbfs/databricks-datasets/COVID/covid-19-data/us-states.csv does not exist: '/dbfs/databricks-datasets/COVID/covid-19-data/us-states.csv'
```

Directly `open` the `README.md` file in [databricks dataset](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-datasets.html) also failed

```py
>>> f = open("/dbfs/databricks-datasets/README.md", "r")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/databricks-datasets/README.md'
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

[image]

Comment: can you add the output of - `%fs ls databricks-datasets/COVID/covid-19-data/us-states.csv`

Comment: `/dbfs` isn't supported on community edition. copy file to local system as described in the linked answer

Comment: Re @Vaebhav: `%fs ls databricks-datasets/COVID/covid-19-data/us-states.csv` returns `dbfs:/databricks-datasets/COVID/covid-19-data/us-states.csv`. Added a screenshot to make it clear.

Comment: Re @AlexOtt: Thanks for the answer! Yes, your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552922/ worked!